# SQLiteBindORColumnindexoutofrangeexception

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I'm new in programming, so I get some issues while implemating the sqlite database:

```
String[] spalten=new String[]{"uebung","datum","ergebnis"};
Cursor cursor1=db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(uebung) FROM freunde", spalten);
cursor1.moveToFirst();
String r=cursor1.getString(0);
```

Does Anyone know what the problem is? I just want to read out the content of the box with the highest level.

Comment: Where is your placeholder `?` ?

Comment: Explain what you want to do and what kind of issues you get. As the above comment mentions, perhaps you have simply forgotten to add your placeholder?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `rawQuery` wrong.

A list of columns to be returned would be used by the `query` method.
`rawQuery` has the column list in the query string itself; `rawQuery`'s second parameter is used for query parameters, which you are not using, so binding them fails.

Just use this:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(uebung) FROM freunde", null);
```